# DataTables dom alignment off

Tags: datatables

My DataTables alignment is off, can anyone tell me why? Have been trying to find a solution, but can't find one:

My dom is:

```
dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-5'B><'col-sm-7'f>>" +
     "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
     "<'row'<'col-sm-4'i><'col-sm-4'p><'col-sm-4'l>>"
```

And the reels is as the picture. I want the pagination to be centered, and the "Show X entries" to be right aligned.

[image]

Comment: What picture? Also which language is that? The code shown above doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy I added the image forgot it sorry.  This is for DataTables.net

Comment: If you could make a snippet of the problem I'd gladly take a look!

Answer (score 1):

Took awhile, but came up with the following:

```
dom: "<'row'<'col-sm-6'B><'col-sm-6'f>><'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>><'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'p>><'row'<'col-sm-12 text-right'i>>"
```

All neat and nice now!